# Notifications upon events

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to configure a custom notification. I'm using a amazon aws instance with Ubuntu 16.04 for the Zabbix Server.
My test scenario is when an application goes down, I get a notification (call an API). Right now, the problem occour that the trigger doesn't call the notification like I meant to and I'd like to know if I took the correct steps to make it.

1) Create a host with ZBX enabled; (working)

2) Create item to monitor - Application with Key value net.tcp.service; (working)

3) Create a trigger to verify when "last" value of net.tcp.service equals zero ({shop_preco:net.tcp.service[http,******, ****].last()}=0); (working)

4) Create a simple test script to use curl to invoke an endpoint of a external API and saved it to alertscripts folder (/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts) ; (working)

5) Create a media type with type "Script" and "Script name" value of the file mentioned on the 4) step; (???)

6) Create an action with a condition "Trigger name contains {item_name}", and one Operation "Send message to users" with "Send only to" value of the media type created on step 5); (???)

[image: Action Log]

Any help it is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you share your zabbix_server.log while triggering the alert? Also, you should check in the web interface the Reports -> Action Log page: in the righmost column you'll find "Ok" or the sending error

Comment: added a image of Action log

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni Should I add a media to the user that is responsable for this action (Administration > Users > [User] > Media > Add)? If yes, in my scenario, what would be the value of "Send to" field?

Comment: Yes, if you want to send a message to a user, you need to assign at least one media to him

Answer (score 0):

It's a basic problem.
First, make sure your script working well,and zabbix user have read&exec permissions for the script file.

Then, you just follow the official document to create the media type.Read this URL
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/notifications/media/script

NOTE: You should use the zabbix user,which you start the zabbix server daemon. zabbix will execute the script by fork a processing from zabbix server daemon.

Third, configure the action.follow this url :https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/notifications/action

After the action working,check the Action log report. see also:https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/reports/action_log

Finally, deal the fault of the action.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link today 
http://cavaliercoder.com/blog/testing-zabbix-actions.html

The problem was solved by adding a media to the user
Administration > Users > [User] > Media > Add